# getting ebay sdk business policies

Tags: c#, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I am new in eBay SDK and eBay trading API. How can I get all business policies(payment, shipping, and return policies) by using API or SDK? I looked into the documentation but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the business policies in [the eBay Trading API](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetUserPreferences.html). From the output of the call what you can expect is described below briefly.

> Inspect the properties of the returned containers to get the preference data for the authenticated user. As applicable, store the data (perhaps in a table), or display it to the user so that they can verify their current preferences.

***A sample C# call***

```
public GetUserPreferencesCall GetEbayUserPreferences()
{
    if (this.Context == null) // context needs to be defined first
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("ApiContext is not defined!");
    }
    GetUserPreferencesCall userPreferences = new GetUserPreferencesCall(Context);
    userPreferences.ShowSellerProfilePreferences = true;

    try { userPreferences.Execute(); }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle exception
    }
    return userPreferences; 
}
```